# "docker pull ubuntu " doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to follow the docker [hello world example](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/examples/hello_world/) but when I enter the following command and my password nothing happens:

```
$ sudo docker pull ubuntu
[sudo] password for mike:
```

It literally stays like that for ages. I've tried on two different Ubuntu 12.04 desktops and it's always the same.

**UPDATE**: What is actually going on is that a new window is opened which is extremely small, when I expand it the window has no content. if I close the window I get the message:

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 32 requests (32 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

**UPDATE 2**: Turns out this isn't a real problem, the program I was running was in fact [not docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018736/docker-opens-up-a-tiny-new-window-that-does-nothing). - A word of warning, `sudo apt-get install docker` on Ubuntu installs another program called docker, not the virtualization tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [debian](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/docker.io) and [ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/docker.io) the package as well as the executable/command is called `docker.io`.

You should better run

```
$ sudo docker.io pull ubuntu
```

Btw.: `docker` is (also) a “system tray for KDE3/GNOME2 docklet applications”.

Answer (score 3):

I reckon this is solved if you install docker correctly as described in your other issue [Docker opens up a tiny new window that does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018736/docker-opens-up-a-tiny-new-window-that-does-nothing)

Answer (score 1):

That's weird! To decompose between a possible `sudo` issue and a `docker` issue, can you try the following:

- first, run `sudo ls`; this should ask for your password, and if successful, it will just list the current directory; but in the process, it will enable your session to use further sudo commands without typing your passwords again;
- then, run `sudo docker ps`; this shouldn't ask for your password, and if successful, this should output one line of header, and return to the prompt;
- finally, try `sudo docker pull ubuntu` and see what happens.

Comment: `sudo docker ps` does exactly the same thing.