# Docker opens up a tiny new window that does nothing

Tags: ubuntu, docker

This is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013731/docker-pull-ubuntu-doesnt-work)-

Under Ubuntu 12.04 when I run any docker command like:

```
sudo docker pull ubuntu
```

The focus is lost from my terminal and a tiny (barely noticeable) new window opens up. When I expand the window there is nothing in it (just blackness). When I close it I get the error message (in the original terminal):

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 32 requests (32 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed `lxc-docker` and not `docker`? There is a package called `docker` which is something totally different!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 2 different programs named "docker". You are using the wrong one.

(I actually just wasted the whole afternoon on this problem too. Hopefully this answer will save someone else some time.)

What you (and I) were hoping to have been using was the "docker" from: https://www.docker.io/

However, what you (and I) were actually using was the "docker" created by Ben Jansens that is a "Docking System Tray".

Here is a short excerpt from the README of this other "docker":

> Docker is a docking application (WindowMaker dock app) which acts as a
>   system tray for KDE3 and GNOME2. It can be used to replace the panel
>   in either environment, allowing you to have a system tray without
>   running the KDE/GNOME panel.

(This is the program creating that tiny window.)

I got this other "docker" by doing a:

> sudo apt-get install docker

... on Linux Mint 16 (Petra). Which is based on Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy).

(You may have done something similar.)

For me the solution was to get rid of this other "docker" with:

> sudo apt-get remove docker

... and (as I am about to do) go get the "docker" from www.docker.io

---

Just a side note, the way I figured this out was by typing the command:

> docker --help

And then noting the name of the author ("Ben Jansens"). And then searching the web for "Ben Jansens docker".

That brought me to this README file:
http://tint2.googlecode.com/svn-history/r31/trunk/src/systray/README

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you followed all of the Docker install instructions, like setting up the right kernel?  http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/ubuntulinux/

If it doesn't work right then something in your configuration is interfering.  If we can't figure out what it is you can always just install Mint or run Docker in Virtual Box or something.

Is it possibly related to this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/975227

Comment: You're right, I was barking up completely the wrong tree. Force of habit made me do "sudo apt-get install docker"